# Labview getting data out of while loop after each iteration

Tags: labview

I want the data out of while or for loops in Stacked Sequence Structure after each iteration..

I want the data out of loops even if it is not stopped that is after each iteration.. to see the plot of data at each iteration and continue to the next loop in the same plot

[image: My code]

somebody please help me ..

I want to send and get data from a device, the data will be plot each time.

thanks..

Comment: What version of LabVIEW? The answer is different in LabVIEW 2016 and later than the earlier versions.

Comment: Is it possible you can rewrite your question to be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Write to a [functional global variable](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Basic-Functional-Global-Variable-Example/ta-p/3503982) inside your data acquisition loop, then read the FGV & plot it in a loop parallel to your sequence structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [queue](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P7OfSAK) to pass data between two different loops:
[image]

Notice the different waiting times on each, in the example it updates around five new points each time to graph.

It should be possible to just [drag the picture into an open vi](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/) to get the code.